# Brute Force in python

Tags: python

I am trying loop the decrypted message 10 times, but I am getting very different results, I don't know why. Below is my code. I have used the same code for encrypting and decrypting. I only had to change the `newchar = newchar-shfit`. Using the same code for looping gets me very different results.

```
  num1=0
  shift=0

  print("Brute force")

  question=input(print("Please enter something to decrypt: "))
  decryptedword = ""
  while num1<10 and shift <10 :


      for character in question:
          newchar = ord(character)
          newchar = newchar - shift
      if newchar < 32:
         newchar = newchar + 95
      elif newchar > 126:
         newchar = newchar - 95
      decryptedword = decryptedword + chr(newchar)


      print(num1,"decrypted word: ",decryptedword)
      num1=num1+1
      shift=shift+1
```

For example if type in `asdasd` in the input, I get:

1 decrypted word:  a

2 decrypted word:  ar

3 decrypted word:  arb

4 decrypted word:  arb^

5 decrypted word:  arb^o

6 decrypted word:  arb^o_

OK, sample output on how it should be, if I input `dvg`, I should get:

1 decrypted word:fxi

2 decrytped word:asd

3 decrypted word:ewh

and so on..

Comment: It's hard to understand what you expect the program to do. Perhaps you could provide sample input and output for how it *should* work

Comment: @PeterGibson please check the edited bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are increasing the `shift` value with every loop iteration, and therefore altering your key with each iteration. And since you are incrementing your key (`shift`) with every iteration your decrypted result is also different in each iteration.

If you remove this line `shift=shift+1` the decrypted message should be the same with every iteration.
(EDIT3: I do not know how to 'strike through' text, but the above lines should be ignored, as I had misunderstood the authors problem.)

EDIT: And another note, your indentation seems to be wrong. The `if ; elif` statement is indented as if they are NOT part of the loop, which also causes unexpected behavior.
EDIT2: Furthermore `decryptedword = ""` Should be inside the loop so it gets reset with every iteration.

```
   num1=0
   shift=0


  print("Brute force")

  question=input(print("Please enter something to decrypt: "))
  while num1<10 and shift <10 :
      decryptedword = ""

      for character in question:
          newchar = ord(character)
          newchar = newchar - shift
          if newchar < 32:
             newchar = newchar + 95
          elif newchar > 126:
             newchar = newchar - 95
          decryptedword = decryptedword + chr(newchar)

      print(num1,"decrypted word: ",decryptedword)
      num1=num1+1
      shift=shift+1
```

Comment: if i remove the shift=shit+1 line, i just get the what i typed in by each characters. for example if i type in abc
i get 
A,
AB,
ABC

Comment: Try do indent your if statement correctly, see edit.

Comment: i had the indentation right already. when i copied to this page, it changed.

Comment: @user2775042 when you copy it to stackoverflow, select the code and click the "{ }" icon. This will insert 4 spaces before each code line allowing it to be correctly formatted. You also seem to have a mix of tabs and spaces - you should be consistent in your indentation. For python, 4 spaces is usually recommended.

Comment: @ArniDat, I think everything below the `while` line should be indented further also in your modified code

Comment: @ArniDat thanks for the second edit. having the decrypted word outside the while loop, changed my output so much.

Comment: @user2775042, if your problem is solved, please mark this as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is all wrong - the if statement needs to be within the for loop

```
print("Brute force")

question=input(print("Please enter something to decrypt: "))
decryptedword = ""
while num1 < 10 and shift < 10:

for character in question:
    newchar = ord(character)
    newchar = newchar - shift
    if newchar < ord(' '):
        newchar = newchar + 95
    elif newchar > ord('~'):
        newchar = newchar - 95
    decryptedword = decryptedword + chr(newchar)


print(num1, "decrypted word: ", decryptedword)
num1 = num1 + 1
shift = shift + 1
```