# Brute force decryption python

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to brute force decrypt a word 58 times but my code keeps adding more characters for every loop it does. Has anyone got any idea what I am doing wrong I just learnt python 3

Here is my attempt to decrypt

```
word = input("Please enter the encrypted word: ")
message = ""
times = 0
for i in range(58):
    for ch in word:
        val=ord(ch)
        times += 1
        val = (val-times)
    if val > ord('z'):
        val = ord('a') + (val - ord('z')-1)
    message +=chr(val)   
    print("Here is your original message: ", message)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `print` statement be outside of your `for` loop?

Comment: Can you specify how the word is encrypted? Is it just a ROT cipher?

Comment: and... what's the use of `times` when you have `i`?

Comment: I'm wondering why are you decrypting data that was so sensitive that it needed to be encrypted 58 times?

Comment: Code doesn't even work (neither in Python2 nor 3).

Comment: imaluengo: why not? what is the error message?
Pynchia: times is inside the second for loop and IIUC accounts for the length of word.
Bob: I'm wondering if the if condition should be moved inside the second for loop? The same for message. Like this, it will only act on the last character of word. If I'm wrong, please specify the encryption method, as Joel C said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brute Force in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849017/brute-force-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
word = input("Please enter the encrypted word: ")
message = ""
times = 0
for i in range(58):
    message = ""
    for ch in word:
        val=ord(ch)
        val = (val-times)
        if val > ord('z'):
            val = ord('a') + (val - ord('z')-1)
        message +=chr(val)   
    print("Here is your encrypted message: ", message)
    times += 1
```

Knowing what kind of encryption was used would make this a much easier problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much this was what i was looking for